# Evento focus() não funciona pelo console dos navegadores

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Sempre que desejo testar algo pela web eu acabo utilizando o console do `browser` (**F12 > Console**) para verificar algum comportando, especialmente se tratando de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). Porém, notei recentemente que o evento [.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) não funciona conforme o esperado.

Vejam o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<input id="teste" type="text" id="teste" />

<br/><br/><br/>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('teste').focus()">teste</button>
```

Se eu clicar no botão **"teste"**, o `input` terá foco, mas se eu digitar o mesmo comando que está no `onclick()` no `console`, nada acontece.

Diante disso, como fazer o `.focus()` funcionar e qual o motivo de isso ocorrer?

> Nota: Isso não occorre só por causa do snippet. Se eu tentar fazer o mesmo com o `input` de pesquisa do SOpt, nada ocorre:
>
> `document.querySelector('.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input').focus();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que seja algo relacionado as *"politicas de comportamentos"*, o mesmo ocorre no Firefox, assim como no Chrome.

Quando você esta no DevTools (console do Chrome ou Firefox) a aba ou janela do navegador não esta em foco e então qualquer `<input>` ou `<textarea>` não irão receber *foco*, um teste simples é adicionar um `timeout` no Console, dentro do próprio site do SOpt abra o console do seu navegador e digite isto:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input').focus();
}, 5000);
```

Você terá 5 segundos para voltar para a aba, então clique em qualquer lugar do site que não seja link, input ou textarea e assim que os 5 segundos passarem o input receberá o foco.

Agora faça outro teste igual, mas ao invés de deixar a aba em foco e digite com `setTimeout` com 5 segundos novamente, aguarde 6 segundos deixe a aba em foco, clique na aba e não na página, notará que ele receberá o foco também, ou seja elementos *"inputables"* só recebem o foco quando a aba ou página esta em foco.

Veja um exemplo sem `timeout`, se eu clicar na aba pra deixa-la em foco, mas não no "body" da página, o input já estará "marcado/sinalizado" para receber o foco quando a aba também estiver em foco:

[image: foco na aba]

Comment: Sei que não está na pergunta, mas existe algum motivo específico para o `.click()` funcionar e o `.focus()` não? Por exemplo, no site do SOpt podemos utiizar isso para ir ao perfil: `document.querySelector('.top-bar .my-profile').click();`

Comment: @Randrade acho totalmente valido pro assunto, já que se refere as politicas de comportamento, note que `.click` funciona na maioria dos casos, outros não irão (tipo abrir certos tipos de janelas), para outras tarefas comum o click é algo que pode ser programável porque a politica de funcionamento provavelmente entende que aquilo não vai afetar o usuário diretamente, ou seja será uma ação dentro da página e não irá controlar o "mouse/rato", já o focus iria provavelmente controlar o ponteiro, e o que fosse digitado entraria no campo. Não posso afirmar com precisão, mas prometo trazer fontes ;)

Answer (score 4):

Porque esta é a forma que o navegador trabalha no console (tanto que ele ignora e retorna *undefined*®).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sempre que você executa um comando no console, o `focus` estará sempre na linha de comando, esperando o próximo comando, ignorando qualquer apontamento de foco para algum elemento na página.

Porém, se você executar o comando abaixo e clicar imediatamente em qualquer parte da página, o foco irá funcionar:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('teste').focus()},5000);
```

**Por que?**

Porque você tirou o foco do console e o comando será executado normalmente após 5 segundos.

---

**Teste aqui no SOpt:**

Execute o comando abaixo no console (F12) e clique imediatamente numa área qualquer da página (área em branco, vazia) ou feche o console:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('#search > input').focus();}, 5000);
```

Comment: Sei que não está na pergunta, mas existe algum motivo específico para o `.click()` funcionar e o `.focus()` não? Por exemplo, no site do SOpt podemos utiizar isso para ir ao perfil: `document.querySelector('.top-bar .my-profile').click();`

Comment: @Randrade O motivo está na resposta. O console não libera o foco a nada, a não ser que vc clique fora dele. Já o click não depende de foco, é um gatilho que o navegador executa normalmente.

Comment: Não ignora e o undefined não tem nada haver com isto, ele retorna undefined porque a função `.focus()` não retorna nada mesmo, se ela fosse "booleana" provavelmente retornaria algo, mas não é. Outra, não é ignorado, o elemento está sinalizado com foco, tanto que se você clicar na aba depois de executar o comando no console vai notar que o foco ocorre no input no momento que a aba recebeu o foco também, mesmo que muito tempo depois, ele só vai perder o foco se você clicar dentro da aba, ou seja em qualquer lugar da página, veja o GIF que postei de teste (cc @Randrade)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Blz. Eu caricaturei o lance do undefined. Sua resposta está excelente, tanto que eu até dei +1 nela. Boa sorte!